# finally block equivalent for exception handling in CompletableFuture

Tags: java-8, completable-future

I have `CompletableFuture` which can return result or exception. I want to perform run some common code in case of exception and normal result. Similar to `try catch finally` block

**Current implementation**

```
CompletableFuture<Integer> future= CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::findAccountNumber)
                             .thenApply(this::calculateBalance)                      
                             .thenApply(this::notifyBalance)
                             .exceptionally(ex -> {
                                 //My Exception Handling logic 
                                 return 0;
                             });
```

Where i can put my finally logic ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The closest equivalent to `finally` is [`whenComplete`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#whenComplete-java.util.function.BiConsumer-). Like `handle`, it accepts a function receiving either, a result value or a throwable, but it doesn’t provide a substitution result value, but rather, the new completion stage will not alter the result, just like `finally`.

So

```
static int decode(String s) {
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(s);
    }
    finally {
        System.out.println("finally action");
    }
}
```

is equivalent to

```
static int decode1(String s) {
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(s)
        .thenApply(Integer::parseInt)
        .whenComplete((myParsedInt, error) -> System.out.println("finally action"))
        .join();
}
```

So when using with

```
for(String s: Arrays.asList("1234", "foo bar")) try {
    System.out.println("decoded: "+decode(s));
} catch(Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("decoding "+s+" failed with "+ex);
}
```

the first variant prints

```
finally action
decoded: 1234
finally action
decoding foo bar failed with java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "foo bar"
```

and the latter prints

```
finally action
decoded: 1234
finally action
decoding foo bar failed with java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "foo bar"
```

Common to both is that an exception thrown within the finally action will supersede the original result, shadowing the exception, if the try block/ previous stage completed exceptionally.

Comment: It is worth noting that (other than finally-blocks) any `.then...`s or `.when...`s are not executed in case of thread interrupts. So this is e.g. not suited for releasing shared resources like locks or streams.

Comment: @SebastianS how do you come to this conclusion? `CompletableFuture`s do not support interruption at all.

Comment: Eventually you'll call `.get()` on a CompletableFuture. Which is interruptible and it will skip any further CompletionStages.

Comment: @SebastianS whether you call `get` or not, has no influence on the execution of the completion stages. What yo you think will happen if two threads invoke `get()` and one of them gets interrupted? What do you think will happen, if a thread calls `get()`, get interrupted, and calls `get()` again, without being interrupted?

Comment: If you run `CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> interruptibleComputation()).whenComplete((r, t) -> log("foo")).get()` and interrupt the thread waiting on `get()`, you'll never see "foo" logged.
What means are there to release resources then?

Comment: @SebastianS unless you terminate the JVM, the action passed to `whenComplete` will be executed. As [can be shown on ideone](https://ideone.com/TVxfge). Again, what happens to the thread invoking `get`, does not influence the computation. It seems, you have an entirely wrong understanding of how `CompletableFuture` works, indicated by naming the method `interruptibleComputation`. You can not interrupt the computation. That’s not supported by `CompletableFuture`.

Answer (score 1):

`handle()` Method  provide more flexible approach. it takes a function receiving either correct result or exception:

**From java doc**

```
handle(BiFunction<? super T,Throwable,? extends U> fn)
```

> Returns a new CompletionStage that, when this stage completes either
>   normally or exceptionally, is executed with this stage's result and
>   exception as arguments to the supplied function.

```
CompletableFuture<Integer> thenApply = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::findAccountNumber)
                         .thenApply(this::calculateBalance)                      
                         .thenApply(this::notifyBalance)        
                         .handle((ok, ex) -> {
                            System.out.println("Code That we want to run in finally ");
                            if (ok != null) {
                                    System.out.println("No Exception !!");
                            } else {

                                System.out.println("Got Exception " + ex.getMessage());
                                return -1;
                            }
                            return ok;
                        });
```